# In Bigquery, I have to create a table in a location EU, by using as select statement of other table which is in a location of europe-west2

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery, I am trying to create a table in a location EU, by using as select statement of other table which is in a location of europe-west2. But I'm getting error like **"Not found: Dataset dmn01-rskxxx-ide-19-4xxx:dmn01_rsk_xxx_xcvv_eu was not found in location europe-west2"**

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Vakcharla, Can you verify if the source table exists in the source dataset? To gain more insight into your issue, can you share  the query and a screenshot of the error?